# PHP how to cut text at comma in string

Tags: php, string

I am looking for a way to cut my strings at comma location.

```
$string1 = 'Something, Other, Display, This';
$string2 = 'Something, Display, This';
$string3 = 'Something, Something, Something, Display, This';
```

these strings are dynamic, they will never be the same, above is only examples of how they can look like.

so here is my problem. How to I display ONLY the "two-last-parts" of the strings?
Meaning, to cut away the rest and only display last 2 parts, nomather how different the strings are.

```
echo 'Display,This';
```

Thanks for any suggestions on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string1 = 'Something, Other, Display, This';
$string2 = 'Something, Display, This';
$string3 = 'Something, Something, Something, Display, This';

echo sprintf("%s\n", displayThis($string1));
echo sprintf("%s\n", displayThis($string2));
echo sprintf("%s\n", displayThis($string3));

function displayThis($s)
{
   if(preg_match("/^.*, (.*, .*)$/", $s, $matches))
      return $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Weston, Almost exactly what I was looking for ;)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [explode method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Explode takes a string and a delimiter, and converts it into an array broken up by that delimiter.

Here's an example of how to use it for what you want:

```
$arr = explode(",", $string); // Gives you an array broken up by commas
$second = array_pop($arr);
$first = array_pop($arr);
echo($first.",".$second);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string1 = 'Something, Other, Display, This';
$strArr=explode(',',$string1);
echo $strArr[count($strArr)-2]." ".$strArr[count($strArr)-1]; // Output: Display This
```

Answer (score 0):

This will explode on the ",", grab the last 2 elements of the array (or 1 if there aren't 2), and them stitch it back together...

```
implode(',', array_slice(explode(',', $string), -2));
```

Comment: This is much more concise than the other answers actually.